Can $S/\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}$ have embedded primes?
This question stems from another question I asked on MathOverflow.
Let $S$ be a regular local ring with prime characteristic $p$. Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be a prime ideal and let $\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}$ denote the ideal generated by the $p$th powers of elements of $\mathfrak{q}$ (so if $\mathfrak{q}=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, then $\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}=(f_1^p,\ldots,f_n^p)$). Then is $\mathfrak{q}$ the only associated prime ideal of $S/\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}$?
Note that $\mathfrak{q}$ is the unique minimal prime ideal of $S/\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}$ since $\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}}=\mathfrak{q}$, so I am asking in other words whether $S/\mathfrak{q}^{[p]}$ can have any embedded prime ideals. All the examples I can think of do not have any embedded prime ideals, so I am not sure whether such an example exists or not.
